# Quick and fast way to generate code [HTML]

Tags: html

There are some videos that I watch,  they use shortcodes like

> div#app

And create **div** with **app** id. Also, they use some numbers and create more than one HTML element quickly. But I do not know how it calls. If you know the name of this language please share. Thanks.

Comment: it is not a language, it is shortcuts of IDEs.

Comment: is it have a name? @tanaydin

Comment: You're looking for probably [Pug](https://pugjs.org/) or [HAML](http://haml.info/)

Comment: @ChrisW. thank you found it. Its is like HAML but named Emmet

Comment: Emmet plugin for your editor.